# SQL Developer after restart resets NLS_LANGUAGE parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Could anyone advice please, what could be the cause of such problem:

After each restart of Oracle SQL developer NLS_LANGUAGE settings are being reset each time.
For example, when just opening a new session, NLS_LANGUAGE is set to LATVIAN and each time when starting SQL Dev, we need to run "alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN'" to set it back to American.

Even that in Options -> NLS everywhere is set American.

We've checked all main lanaguage/location/region settings and set American everywhere, but still after re-launch only NLS_LANGUAGE setting is being reset, rest (like NLS_TERRITORY) are fine.

What hasn't been changed that triggers each time that reset?

Comment: You set it in the oracle db via query, or you choose it in some client query tool options panel?

Comment: In the sql developer's preferences (then it's query tool), yes.

Comment: version of sqldev? and tell me about your machine - is the machine's regional settings set to a Latvian environment? are other settings being reset as well, or JUST this one? change another setting and see if it persists - could be just a matter or OS privs to where we write the preferences to

Comment: If the SQL Developer NLS prefs show American on launch, but your sessions are opened in Latvian - do you have a database or schema after-logon trigger that is altering the session?

Comment: do you have checkbox at the bottom of the preference panel on or off? 'SKIP NLS SETTINGS'

Comment: Hi, sorry for late replies, but answers are such : 
skip nls settings is off. 
Hard to say what triggers - but usually after disconnect- > reconnect to DB it resets back again to Latvian.

We have sql dev 18.3, Win 10, regional settings are set to American.. this is what confuses me more..

and only language is being reset, NLS_TERRITORY or others are the same

Answer (score 1):

You can change in Preferences. Search for NLS and change Language to AMERICAN

Answer (score 0):

1. use Notepad++ to cut/paste DML into TOAD or SQL*Developer
   or
2. run at the host level, setting env variables `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

   export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8